# How to load a JS library (in a custom module) from a theme using only JS?

Tags: 8

I want custom subthemes, one for admin and one for front end. both need to load the leaflet js library that im trying to put into a custom module.

Ive got the subtheme bit working, and my global-scripts js running, but cant get module loaded or running.

*themes/angas_admin/*

**angas_admin.info.yml**

```
# subtheme by haydent httech.com.au
name:  Angas Admin
type: theme
description: 'seven subtheme by hayden - httech.com.au'
core: 8.x
base theme: seven

libraries:
  - angas_admin/global-styling
  - angas_admin/global-scripts
  - angas_module/leaflet  

regions:
  header: 'Header'
  pre_content: 'Pre-content'
  breadcrumb: Breadcrumb
  highlighted: Highlighted
  help: Help
  content: Content
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'
  sidebar_first: 'First sidebar'
regions_hidden:
  - sidebar_first
```

**angas_admin.libraries.yml**

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
global-scripts:    
  version: 1.x 
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
```

*modules/angas_module/*

**angas_module.info.yml**

```
name: Angas Module
description: map by haydent httech.com.au
type: module
core: 8.x

libraries:
  - angas_module/leaflet
```

**angas_module.libraries.yml**

```
leaflet:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/leaflet.css: {}
  js:
    js/leaflet.js: {}
```

Comment: This looks largely correct, have you enabled `angas_module`? (You can't depend on an uninstalled module). Furthermore, I'd remove `libraries: - angas_module/leaflet` from `angas_module.info.yml` because this would unconditionally load Leaftlet on ALL pages.

Comment: Yes, angas_module is enabled. the bit you suggest to remove ive tried a few different ways to load the module library by the subtheme. its fine if its loaded on all pages. in the themes script.js i have the code that looks for specific element in a page and insert/run leaflet code on it to generate map. i just want leaflet library available to my 2 subtheme angas_admin and angas_front (not mentioned but to come)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your module's library as a dependency of your theme's library (or any other library that depends on it). This will ensure it's always loaded and available for your theme's library. See [Declaring dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195#s-declaring-dependencies) in d.o's docs.

For example, in your theme's libraries.yml file:

```
global-scripts:    
  version: 1.x 
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - angas_module/leaflet
```

After adding it as a dependency for your libraries, remove it from your theme's .info.yml file (not needed). And remove it from the module's .info.yml file (also not needed).

Comment: So among other things I had tried this approach, which didnt work either, but after your recommendation It gave me confidence to think a little broader and tried the "clear all caches" button in the performance section of admin and this fixed it. Even though in that section I dont have caching or aggregation enabled ... Is there some way to stop this caching while im developing at least ? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I found out how to disable caching.